# How to execute file in DOS after any program exits?

Tags: batch-file, assembly, x86, dos, code-injection

I am using MS-DOS 6.22. This is not command prompt.
I need to execute a batch file or .com file after every/any program terminates and returns to the command line. I don't believe a batch file will work for this cause it would have to be a separate batch for every single program on the system.
I believe a code injection into command.com may be necessary. Is there anyone out there who is familiar with the internals of DOS or assembly language?
If you think you have a simpler solution, please let me know.

Comment: You can write a TSR that hooks interrupt 20h, 27h, and the interrupt 21h functions 00h, 31h, and 4Ch. You'd still be in the process that requests termination at that point though.

Comment: Do you also want your handler to execute when a program executes another and that nested program exits?  Or do you only care about program exits that return to the command interpreter?

Comment: Only when the program exits and returns to command.com

Comment: Are you executing the _same_ program/batch file after every program exits? Why do you need this?

Comment: Can you live with it, when you have to use a batchfile to run your commands? Like `run edit test.bat`, where `run.bat` basically is `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9` and `echo program "%1" finished.` (obviously replace/extend the second line to what you really want to do)

Comment: Yes, the same file should be executed after every exit. I have a program that changes the DOS interface and text mode and after every time a program quits, it goes back again, so I have to re-run it each time. It's complicated. So I just need that program to run.

Comment: @Synaps3 The usual solution is to wrap that program in a batch script that issues a `MODE` command right afterwards to restore the video mode.  Are you sure that's not a suitable solution for your problem?

Comment: @fuz Well, I'd need to do that for every single program, right?

Comment: @Synaps3 For every program that messes up the video mode, correct.  But it sounds like you only have one that does.  Try to solve the problem you have, not a more general problem.  It is certainly possible to do what you ask for, it's just not easy and will involve some tricky DOS programming.

Comment: @fuz No, any program that isn't text mode messes it up. So it's a lot. If you think you can offer a serious solution, I'd pay for it. (That's for anyone out there.)

Comment: @Synaps3 Okay, I'll have a look.

Comment: I believe the desired functionality can be achieved in DOS 3.0 or newer using INT 2F/AH=AEh.  Might be slightly tricky to get right though.

Comment: If you are interested in commissioning such a program, please send me an email to the address found on my website.

Comment: @fuz OK, I'll check that out. Thanks. I have the question on a forum as well, so if I don't get a solution, I'll contact you.

Comment: What about using some other shell besides COMMAND.COM that might already have a feature to run a command before every prompt?  I have a vague recollection that 4DOS had features along those lines.  Alternatively, patch COMMAND.COM itself.